# Creating a "solution" in math document

Tags: answers

Is there a tidy way to print solutions like there is for proofs?  Something like the following but for solutions.

```
 \begin{proof}
   ...
 \end{proof}
```

Comment: Should the solutions be numbered or unnumbered? Do you use a package such as either `amsthm` or `ntheorem`?

Comment: Not numbered.  Just say "solution." Then solution begins and at the end has a white or black square.  Preferably white to match \begin{proof}.

Answer (score 2):

(Modified the answer after the OP mentioned that he uses the `amsthm` package.)

I'm assuming that the solution environment shouldn't be numbered. If that's correct, and in view of the fact you appear to use the `amsthm` package, you could set up a solution-like environment, named `soln`, as follows in the preamble, after loading the `amsthm` package:

```
\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem*{soln}{Solution}
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it clashes with amsthm.  I get the following error: Package ntheorem Error: Theorem style plain already defined. ...rfont ##1\ ##2\ (##3)\theorem@separator]}

Comment: My homework has both proofs and answers in it so I want to have some say "proof." in which I have been using amsthm, and I want some to say "solution."

Answer (score 2):

Just duplicate `proof`:

```
\newenvironment{solution}
  {\begin{proof}[Solution]}
  {\end{proof}}
```

If you plan to have “variable” labels (say “Sketch of solution” in one of the uses), do

```
\newenvironment{solution}[1][Solution]
  {\begin{proof}[#1]}
  {\end{proof}}
```

Comment: This worked after I used \renewenvironment because it said \solution was already defined.  Thank you for your answer!